# structures and structure pointers. Member accessibility

Tags: pointers, linux-kernel, global-variables, structure

I am trying to understand the concepts of Structures and Structure pointers in C. I was trying to implement a piece of code and got stuck here.

Problem task:
I have to constantly poll for a variable member x in a structure, A. And I want to run a kthread in the background to control x's value but the input data to the kthread is another structure B.

B contains another structure C which can be used to access A dynamically. But here's whats going wrong..whenever I call A from B using pointers, I receive a NULL pointer. I am not able to access the global copy of A.

Lets have a look at the code. The code won't work, its a dummy case. I just want to make sure I am not making any syntactical or logical errors. 
Let me know if I am missing any details in my question.
Here its is:

```
In <File.h>

struct A {
   int var;
   struct pqr;

};

struct C {
   struct platform_device *pdev;
   ..
};

struct B {
   struct C *c;
   struct notifier_block abc;
   .. 
};

int control_function(void *data);
int polling_function(struct A *a1);
```

---

```
In <File1.c>

int main ()
{
  int rc;
  struct B *b = malloc(sizeof(struct B));

  b->notifier_block.notifier_call = some_random_funtion;
  rc = fb_register_client (&b->abc);

  kthread_run(control_function, b, "ctrl_fnc");
  return rc;
 }
```

---

```
\\Meanwhile all the structures are getting populated elsewhere dynamically
```

---

```
In <File2.c>

int control_function(void *data)
{
struct B *b = (struct B *)data;
struct A *a; 
struct C *c1; 
c1 = b->c;    //is this right? because this in the output shows still unpopulated and I cant update struct A without accessing the global copy of struct C 

a = container_of(dev_get_platdata(&c1->pdev->dev, struct A, pqr);

a->var = 1;
return 0;
}

int polling_function(struct A *a1)
{
  int ret;

 ret = a1->var;

 return ret;
}
```

Comment: 1. What is in the platdata? `struct pqr *`? 
2. `c1 = b->c;` is okay, though your code doesn't show where it's populated.